# How to use custom plugin in Resco mobile CRM?

Tags: mobile, dynamics-crm-2013

I have some questions related to Resco Mobile CRM, I am using online version of MSCRM 2011

1) I have created a plugin for create of custom entity, how can I make it trigger when I create a record in Resco Mobile( ipad) app.
2) When I create a record in service activity and if it conflict with resources availability an alert appears on the top of the form. In Resco mobile app the same is not appearing. Is it designed to be in this way or am I missing something
3) I have a requirement which I handle in MSCRM by adding subgrids of related entities in the custom entity form. How can I achieve the same in Resco Mobile App.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you create/edit a record in Mobile CRM, if you are working in online mode, the records are created/edited immediately and the it is handled the same way like you would create it directly on the server. If you are working in offline, after synchronizing the changes with the server, the records are handled the same way as they will be created on the server (only the created on/modified on fields will have different date and time).
2. Mobile CRM application works with the data from the CRM server, but not with plugins. If you require such validation, you will need to customize the Mobile CRM application and create the form validation using Woodford configurator (Rules or Java Script) or use the custom development.
3. This can be achieved using the JavaScript and offline HTML in Woodford configurator. Or using the custom development.

In case of number 2. and 3., you can try the Woodford configurator, and in case you will have any questions or problems, please contact us at mobilecrm@resco.net.

Lukas Lesko

resco.net